# Adding random number to uploaded file in PHP

Tags: php, file, upload, filenames

I have my upload php code where my intent is , obtained file from `$_files`,
add a **random number** between 0 and 9999 to the name of image like this:

`image sent` : image.jpg 
`before saving` : image321.jpg

the image is saved in my upload folder but the filename are like
**"php2983204tmp"**

```
if ($file !== null) {
    $rand = rand(0000,9999);
    $path = "some_path";

    $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName(); // file
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // jpg

    $file->move($path, $file_name.$rand.$extension);

    $response = "File loaded successfully: " . $file_name.$extension;
    $response .= '<br>size: ' . filesize($path . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName()) / 1024 . ' kb';

    return new Response($response);
```

any ideas to fix?

Answer (score 1):

The filename in your example is `php` and your extension is `tmp`. None of them have the `.` that you are missing.

You need to add the dot `.` as a string after the `$file_name` and `$rand`, before the `$extension` like this:

```
$file->move($path, $file_name.$rand. "." .$extension);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add in the desired chars to the actual string.

```
$file->move($path, $file_name.$rand.".".$extension);
```

But I have to say, I am against how you've done this, you don't even check if the "newly" created string already exists in the directory. Its better to hash the time of upload with the original filename, rename the file to the new hash and use a database to point to the file as this way the filename collisions don't occur.

```
$fn = md5(microtime(true) . $extension  . $file_name);

$file->move($path, $fn);
```

Answer (score 0):

***TIME*** is always unique identity, use it as below (maybe helpful):

```
             if ($file !== null) {
                $rand = rand(0000,9999).time();
                $path = "some_path";
                $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName(); // file
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // jpg
                $file->move($path, $file_name.$rand.$extension);
                $response = "File loaded successfully: " . $file_name.$extension;
                $response .= '<br>size: ' . filesize($path . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName()) / 1024 . ' kb';
            return new Response($response);
```